# Why is box shadow inefficient and what to do about it?

Tags: performance, css

Every time I try to use box shadows with a greater value than a few pixels of blur I hit performance issues that make the slick operation of the page visibly degrade. I see a tiny increase in RAM and a significant increase in processing power.

What are the reasons for box shadow having such a noticeable effect on page performance, as observed in the browser, and client CPU consumption? I know that page redrawing is an issue, but this still seems to be a problem when I have a static div with something sliding over it and I have even seen it as a problem with a static background.

Also, what tips are there for improving box shadow performance?

Comment: If the only answer is "modify how the browser implements box-shadow", there's not much you can do other than submit a patch to said browser vendor.

Comment: Is this issue with a specific browser, or all browsers?

Comment: its certainly been an issue with Chrome,

Comment: I am using quite an old PC, 2meg RAM, 2gig processor, but still more powerful than a lot of mobiles